# How to authenticate sudo in 1 command?

Tags: sudo

I was wondering if there was any way I can use a sudo "one-liner", for script purposes, for example

sudo -p PASSWORD {command},
instead of
sudo {command}
*Prompt for password:*

Comment: I believe that there is a way to do it with `sudo -S`, but I'm not sure.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming and is off-topic. You *might* have better luck on [unix.se], but you should carefully review what's on and off topic there before posting.